# Custom fonts are not rendered when using DomPortalOutlet

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, fonts

I'm working on an Angular 9 multi-project app and I'm trying to detach a component from the main container, just so the window can be moved on the screen freely (like a widget). I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/@saranya.thangaraj/open-angular-component-in-a-new-tab-without-bootstrapping-the-whole-app-again-e329af460e92), and it seems to work the most, since everything is copied from the styles file except for the custom fonts added to the project. The `styles.css` file contains a series of `@font-face` definitions for custom fonts imported within the `assets` folder of a shared project (which too belongs to the main application), but those fonts don't seem to be rendered, and the default browser's ones are used instead.

The structure of my application, which is a multi-project one, is the following:

> main-app 
> | ---- project X (with custom fonts imported from shared) 
> | ---- shared (with custom fonts in the "assets/font" folder

If I inspect the HTML of the detached window, though, I can see that all the styles are corretly copied from the parent view, including the `styles.css` one with all the fonts references, but the texts are still not rendered correctly.

Do you have any suggestions to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like custom icons too are not copied to the detached window, hence they are not rendered as well... :-(

Comment: Another update: it seems like "queryselectorall" suggested by that guide only manages to copy the styles, but does not import external resources, like fonts or icons, correctly. Color and simple styling, like border-radius or backgrounds, do work, though.